# angularJS ng-src with trustAsResourceURL

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to create an iframe in my webpage with `ng-src="localhost/test/public/getreportsdata/1"`. I used the trust source function `$sce.trustAsResouceUrl` and that's to open the result of the service in the iframe.

I tested it on my laptop it worked, now on my desktop it giving me :

> cannot read property 'trustAsResourceUrl' of undefined

My html iframe :

```
<iframe width="800" height="800" ng-src="{{trustSrc(reportbydateresource.src)}}"></iframe>
```

My js code :

```
angular.module('backOfficeApp')
.controller('CheckReportsCtrl', CheckReportsCtrl);
CheckReportsCtrl.$inject=['$scope','$http','$filter'] ;
function CheckReportsCtrl($scope,$http,$filter,$sce){
$scope.trustSrc = function (src){
return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl9src); };
$scope.reportbydateresouce={src:"localhost/test/public/getreportsdata/1"}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Be carefull, You forgot to inject $sce service CheckReportsCtrl.$inject=['$scope','$http','$filter'] ; --> CheckReportsCtrl.$inject=['$scope','$http','$filter', '$sce'] ;

Comment: $sce is not a privider to inject it here, it gives : unknown privider: $sceProvider  when i tried to inject $sce

Comment: You should inject $sce if you want to use it. Your error "unknow provider ..." means angular failed initializing (https://plnkr.co/edit/bczfuhKEnyaef71q2S0R?p=preview)

Comment: I tried to inject it, but error : unknow provider only for $sce, what's wrong ? AngularjS version ? on laptop 1.5.8 (working) on desktop 1.4.6(givine error)

Comment: solved, solution : I was including angular.min.js angularjs.js and angular.js i removed the angularjs.js from version 1.5.8 and problem solved. Thank you

Comment: Please post your answer for other people :)

Comment: am new to stack ) i will check how thank you )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Injecting $sce with providers

```
.controller('CheckReportsCtrl', CheckReportsCtrl);
 CheckReportsCtrl.$inject=['$scope','$http','$filter','$sce'] ;
```

2- I was including angular.min.js angularjs.js and angular.js i removed the angularjs.js from version 1.5.8 and problem solved.